# Retrofit - Parsing unexpected data type

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit library in Android Kotlin project

And want to handle parsing unexpected data types.

for example if the JSON:

```
{
  "boolean": true,
  "number": "123",
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

And the data class will be

```
data class Response (
        val boolean: Boolean? = null,
        val number: Int? = null,
        val string: String? = null
)
```

Normally Retrofit will fail to parse the response and `onFailure()` will be called, as retrofit fail to parse the attribute `number` as it is returned as string and it is expected to be number, and the whole object will fail to parse.

What I want, to process the request normally just the unparsed field should be null.

Comment: You'd have to implement your own system for that.

Comment: What do you mean by system, you mean ConverterFactory or adapter or you mean create my own library, I read a little in how retrofit works but I didn't understand it quite will.

Comment: You have to write code to parse the json. And since you're using Kotlin it's slightly easier since you can take an unknown object and call `.toString().toInt()` and catch exceptions if it fails (i.e. not an integer). Not familiar with retrofit, so I have no clue what classes you have to override, but you basically have to write a system for parsing it independently of type

Comment: @Andrew Hossam Your "number" is in String type and you are retrieving in Int? type you need to parse your String to Int first.

Comment: Yes I know @VívêkBåräì, that what I need to handle , I expect it to be Int but if it came from the backend as string or any another type even object, then making the attribute = null instead of exception

Comment: @Andrew Hossam I don't know kotlin coding but i think number might be some keyword there did you check that?

Comment: @AndrewHossam check this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)